# 403 despite of 'require all granted' in every directory

Tags: apache-2.4

I tried to run a simple apache 2.4.12 server with a single static index.html page only. After some configuration it starts correctly, but client gets the 403 response with "Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server."

httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"

Listen 80

LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

<IfModule unixd_module> User daemon Group daemon

</IfModule>

ServerAdmin you@example.com

ServerName myip:80

<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted </Directory>


DocumentRoot "/home/nnc/www" 
<Directory "/home/nnc/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted </Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html </IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied </Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" common </IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/" </IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module> </IfModule>

<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted </Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress.Z
    AddType application/x-gzip.gz.tgz </IfModule>

<IfModule proxy_html_module> Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf </IfModule>

<IfModule ssl_module> SSLRandomSeed startup builtin SSLRandomSeed connect builtin </IfModule>
```

Comment: Why do you have three <Directory> settings? And why is the first one defined before DocumentRoot? And why is the third one defined in an area outside of the DocumentRoot (I think you might need an Alias to work if you want that - see here: http://cybergav.in/2009/08/28/how-to-use-multiple-document-roots-in-apache/)?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved after finding this clue in logs:

> [Tue Jun 30 09:43:19.158971 2015] [core:error] [pid 7735:tid 140653090862848] (13)Permission denied: [client censored_ip:44459] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/home/nnc/www') **because search permissions are missing on a component of the path**

I had to change the permissions to 755 not only to 'www' folder but also to 'nnc'.